# Where I can write business logic when I want to create other instance using Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Where I can write myself logic when I use Rest Framework?

I have a serializers:

```
class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    order_num = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('name', 'room',  'price', 'order_num')

    def get_order_num(self, obj):
        return str(now()) + "111"
    def get_price(self, obj):
        print(obj, "liao obj")

        return "0.10"
```

And I have a views:

```
class OrderCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
```

The models is below:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    order_num = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    room = models.ForeignKey(to=Room, related_name="orders")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This demo is my test demo, don't care the details.

And my goal is want to create a instance of room when I access the view/serializer.

[image]

You see the snapshot, I can create the Order instance success, but my goal is when create a Order, I want to create a Room instance(don't care the room's initial data, just for test we can set it constant data). and return the room's id.

I don't know where to do to create Room instance logic. some friends can help me with that?

---

**EDIT**

in the django rest framework docs, I find I can override the create method to realize my requirement:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

But, this is a aspect(means in serializer), how to realize in views.py ?

Comment: Is this something you're looking for: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ ?

Comment: I scan the docs, and find I can in serializer to override the create method to realize my requirement, but how about in views.py?

Comment: The unspoken rule is to have serializers responsible for your API objects. However, you can also extend `perform_create` of `OrderCreateAPIView` to create a room.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thanks, I understand it, thank you very much.